# How can I use Kafka window(by time) to split kstream in parts and get records from the last window?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I manage to get all records from KStream, but I need records from only the last window.
Could you provide me with an example of code please.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Also, what to you mean by "only the last window" -- because input is in infinite stream, there is no such thing as a "last" window, because new windows are created when new data arrives all the time.

Comment: Ok, then how can I get records from a certain window?

Comment: By default, KS does not store raw records of window, but the current aggregate because that is more efficient. You could change the `Aggregator` to return a `List` (or similar) to accumulate the input records though.